# Modular Arithmetic Proof: Attempt and Need Help

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

***Prove:***

There exists an integer $a$ s.t. for all $b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$

**IF**

- $2b^2(b-4) \not \equiv 3(2c + 3) + (1-2c)^3 $ mod 10$ $
- $2b^2(b-4) \not \equiv 3(2d + 3) + (1-2d)^3 $ mod 10$ $
- $2c^2(c-4) \not \equiv 3(2d + 3) + (1-2d)^3 $ mod 10$ $

**THEN**

- $2a^2(a-4) \not \equiv 3(2(b + c + d) + 3) + (1-2(b+c+d))^3 $ mod 10$ $

**Attempt**

- I tried simplifying a general formula with $p, q$ to:
- $2p^3 + 2p^2 \not \equiv 2q^3 + 2q^2 $ mod 10$ $
- I started working with cases for $b$ and what $c, d$ would need to be to satisfy not congruence.
- It is very tedious and I'm not sure my approach is correct.

Any Ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: I agree it looks very tedious.  Where does this question arise from?

Comment: A university proofs class problem.